# Initializing double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, initialization

I have been writing this code for double linked list but according to the debugging tool there's some segmentation faults. Compiles fine but explodes at run.

header file

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED


struct Node
{
     int data;
     Node* next; //next node
     Node* prev; //prev node
};

typedef struct 
{
     Node* first; //aims to first node
     Node* last;  //aims to last node
} List;

void initList(List &l);
```

Linked list cpp

```
#include <cstddef>
#include "List.h"

void initList(List &l)
{
    l.first->data = -1;
    l.first = NULL;
    l.first->prev = NULL;

    l.last->data = -2;
    l.last->next = NULL;
    l.last->prev = NULL;
}
```

main

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "List.h"


    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        List nlist;

        initList(nlist);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *Compiles fine but explodes at run* -- "Compiling fine" doesn't really mean anything.  All it means is that your C++ syntax is legal -- it has no bearing on whether you have logical or other runtime errors.  Also `typedef struct` is from `C`.  What book(s) is (are) teaching you old C-style coding?

Comment: You are missing the following key concepts that you need to fully understand before you can implement your linked list: 1. Class construction and initialization; 2. Automatic and dynamic scope. You apparently didn't recognize that your list members must be instantiated. You need to go back and reread the relevant chapters in your C++ book. There are too many problems with the shown code.

Comment: It's also a clear case of a linked list that isn't linked. OP NULLing the pointers doesn't mean they are initialized to anything sensible in the context of a linked list. The recommendation that OP reads up on the topic still holds. It's obvious that they don't yet get it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, i was expecting more light on the matter but i managed to figure it out. Also i forgot to add that the code posted above wasn't the full code (Since it was above 100+ lines i focused on what i thought was the problem)

The segmentaion fault was from an if statement which was involved in many other functions.

the constructor you were talking about.

```
Node* initNode(int data)
{
    Node* nNode = new Node;
    nNode->data = data;
    nNode->next = NULL;
    nNode->prev = NULL;

    return nNode;
}
```

and the function where the segmentaion fault actually was.

```
bool isEmpty(List l)
{
   if((l.first->next == NULL) && (l.last->prev == NULL))
   {
        return true;
   }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Sorry for the misleading post and thanks for the help.